# Installation of Gradle

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gradle, installation

I have already install gradle, 1 week ago, and when I did the command "gradle -v", the console displayed all the information about this.

Now, the things I had installed with gradle are still in usr/local/gradle repertory but when I do "gradle -v"  the console says that gradle is not installed.

Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this :

**Open your .profile file in gedit.**

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

**Paste the following at the bottom of your .profile file.**

```
# Gradle
if [ -d "$HOME/usr/local/gradle" ]; then
    export GRADLE_HOME="$HOME/usr/local/gradle"
    PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
fi
```

**Finally, source your .profile and test gradle.**

```
source ~/.profile

which gradle

gradle -version
```

Comment: I solve it, but I have always to do "export PATH=/usr/local/gradle/gradle-2.8/bin:$PATH"  and "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40" before to do something with gradle ?

Comment: Which means u havent even set the JDK path . Follow these steps --->
1.type `gksudo gedit /etc/environment` in ur terminal
2.paste this `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40`
3.export JAVA_HOME
4.Save your file and exit gedit
5.Lastly, reload the system PATH with the following command:
`$ . /etc/environment`